# Securely encrypt and decrypt files via PBE in Java (Jasypt seems insecure)

Tags: encryption, aes, java, file-encryption, pbkdf2

This post has been **MOVED** to StackOverflow due to lack of answers on Info Security:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60960802/securely-encrypt-and-decrypt-files-via-pbe-in-java-jasypt-seems-insecure

---

Considered solutions were Jasypt and Google Tink but neither worked well for Java. See above stackoverflow post for details.

I have not looked at [libsodium](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/) yet.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/meixler/web-browser-based-file-encryption-decryption for a javascript based solution for encrypting/decrypting files using PBKDF2 and AES.

Comment: Have you looked at libsodium ? It seems to have quite a few bindings for java : https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/bindings_for_other_languages/

Comment: @mti2935 and user2313067 - thank you so much for the responses. Since no one else has given me a response that fully answers my question, in a few days I will be moving this post to stackoverflow.com.